# Git: How to overwrite a specific file both in staging/index and local

Tags: git

> ***EDIT*** I am looking for a single command

Please note I am looking for ***file specific*** operation and not commit level operations. At commit level I know it can be done using different flags. So here is my scenario:

I have a single file: ***test.txt***

My repo file contains a text:

```
first change
```

My staging file ***AND*** my working dir file contains a text:

```
first change second change
```

> Now if I do `git rest HEAD test.txt` the state of affairs is following

1. My repo file contains: `first change` [*nothing changed here*]
2. My index file looks:`first change` [***changed to match repo file***]
3. Working dir file : `first change second change` [*nothing changed here*]

> What is the command to get into following state:

1. My repo file contains: `first change` [*nothing changed here*]
2. My index file looks: `first change` [***changed to match repo file***]
3. Working dir file : `first change` [***changed to match repo file***]

Comment: so as @ rohit  jain pointed out the command is `git checkout HEAD -- file`

Comment: In your "second scenario", the description for item #2 is incorrect: the index *is* updated by `git checkout`.  To this, use either `git status` or `git diff --cached`.

Comment: @ torek. My bad. BTW is there any command which leaves it to that state?

Comment: Not precisely, but `git show revspec:path > path` gets you that result.  The `show` command does not obey smudge filters, however (hence the "not precisely" part).

Comment: @torek i will try and let you know

Comment: If you don't have smudge and clean filters, it will indeed work (I know, I've used it :-) ).  `git show HEAD:test.txt > test.txt`, in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always do this with `git reset HEAD file` followed by `git checkout -- file`.

You can also do this with a single command (this I came to know of recently):

```
git reset --hard HEAD file  # oops!! doesn't work on paths...
```

Seems like the *previous command doesn't work on paths.* In that case, you can use this one:

```
git checkout HEAD -- file
```

Note the usage of `--`. That will replace both staged and working copy of that file.

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder I just added.

Comment: @RohitJain: `git reset --hard HEAD file` gives me a very specific error: '*fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.*'

Comment: @Dolda2000 Ah! Didn't know that. Added another command which works.

Comment: @ Rohit have you tried it. Nine of the flags --soft --mixed or --hard does not work on file level ops